# How can I publish my scala play project without application.conf?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, publish, typesafe-activator

In my case I run this commands for publish my scala project library:

```
./activator clean compile
./activator test
./activator publish-local
```

I need my local library application.conf only for tests.

But I wanna use application.conf of my new project
 which use this library jar as dependency.

How can I build jar without application.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { (ms: Seq[(File, String)]) =>
  ms filterNot { case (file, dest) =>
    dest.contains("application.conf")
  }
}
```

This is adapted from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37598479/1205368) (removing files from dist task output), but should work here also